# entering if when True

Tags: powershell

writing a Powershell script to monitor a log file and have a condition for a fail over to a redundant connection that needs a service to be restarted.

```
$cond = "WARN: Attempting auto reconnect to Host"
$lfil = "c:\temp_logs\error.log"
Get-Content $lfil -wait | Select-String -Quiet $cond
if(true) {
    write-host "restarting due to fail over "
    Stop-service "Outbound HL7"
    Rename-Item -Path $lfil -NewName "c:temp_logs\error_restart.log"
    Start-sleep 2
    Start-Service "Outbound HL7"
} else {
    write-host "no match"
}
```

in the ISE i get a line when the condition is met True,   but cant enter in the if condition,  tried the $_.   I know this has to be really simple but very new to Powershell and looking things up is pointing me in a bunch of different directions.  Any guidance would be greatly apprciated.

Joe

Answer (score 2):

You're looking to operate on whether or not your [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) found a match.

Adding `-Quiet` *outputs* a Boolean that indicates that; it does *not* set an *exit code* in the manner that calls to *external programs* do.

Thus, instead of trying to test for the outcome *after* the `Select-String` call, directly evaluate the call *itself*:

```bash
if (Get-Content $lfil -wait | Select-String -Quiet $cond) { 
  ...
}
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `if (true) { ...`

`true` is interpreted as a *command* in this case; there is no such command built into PowerShell, so it'll look for an *external program* named `true`, which is unlikely to exist on Windows, but does exist on Unix-like platforms, where it produces *no output* and only sets an *exit code*; however, `if` only acts on *output*, and *empty* output is considered falsey, so the conditional is always *false*.

If you wanted to operate on the most recent command's *success status*, PowerShell's [automatic `$?` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#section-1) reflects that: however, unlike in POSIX-like shells such as `bash`, where it contains the most recent statement's *exit code*, in PowerShell it is an *abstract* indicator reflecting either `$true` or `$false` (PowerShell's Boolean constants).

`$?` is rarely used in PowerShell, and it doesn't quite operate the same way that it does in POSIX-compatible shells, because native PowerShell commands do *not* use exit codes to communicate success vs. failure. Thus, `$?` usually just tells you whether a genuine *error* occurred, not whether a *condition* was met or not. E.g., after executing `'a' | Select-String 'b'`, `$?` still contains `$true`, since no *error* occurred during execution (the string was simply not found). As with `Select-String -Quiet`, PowerShell-native commands in general indicate success vs. failure via a Boolean *output* value, as the `Test-*` cmdlets such as [`Test-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path) do.

However, for commands that *do* set (process) exit codes - *external programs* and potentially also `.ps1` script (primarily if they're designed to be called from *outside* PowerShell) - it is reflected in the [automatic `$LastExitCode` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode).

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell the literal term `true` has no meaning. The PowerShell version of the `True/true` constants many other languages use is instead `$true`.

```
if ($true) { Write-Host 'True' }
```

That being said you also can use other values that can be cast to the `true` boolean value to satisfy an if condition such as

```
if (1) { Write-Host 'True' }
```

and

```
if ('non-empty string') { Write-Host 'True' }
```

just to name a few

Comment: Ok,   so tried if($true)... still doesnt seem to enter the condition,   the log may have more than one entry so use the -Quiet to just detect if we have a match.. which without i get a few entries as the logs update faster than i can detect and trigger a stop,  rename the log so i dont get a false re-trigger,   then start once again which will create a new log.  at this time just trying to proof of concept this type of fix.  I can find the content in the logs,   just appears acting upon it is where i am struggling.

Comment: @mxcrash wait so when you ran `if($true) { Write-Host "restarting due to fail over " } else { Write-Host "no match" }` it printed `no match`?

Comment: using ISE to test,   when i change the if statement to that you have and have the condition in the file as removing the -Quiet shows 4 matches.. the if condition seems to be ignored all together,  on match on the then or else.

Comment: PS C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> C:\Bernoulli\bin\restart.ps1
True

Comment: Huh, can you post your full code?

Comment: this is it, just remarked out the lines i am not interested in running..                                                                                                  
$cond = "WARN: Attempting auto reconnect to Host"
$lfil = "c:\temp_logs\error.log"
Get-Content $lfil -wait | Select-String -Quiet $cond
if($true) {write-host "restarting due to fail over " } else {write-host "no match" }
#Stop-service "Outbound HL7"
#Rename-Item -Path $lfil -NewName "c:temp_logs\error_restart.log"
#Start-sleep 2
#Start-Service "Outbound HL7"
#} else {
#write-host "no match"
#}